# SignalR - Como enviar mensagem para todos exceto o chamador

Tags: mvc, asp-net-core, signalr

Tenho uma aplicação Aspmet core 3.1 MVC onde tenho configurado um hub SignalR.

Tenho uma controller onde eu passo por injeção de dependência o `IHubContext`.

```
private readonly IHubContext<MesHub> _hubContext;
```

Na minha classe `MesHub`, eu tenho um metodo de conexão.

```
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        if (name == null)
            name = "Service";

        Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, name);

        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
```

Já debuguei o metodo e aprincipio funciona super bem.

Para enviar uma mensagem para todos os usuários que estão conectados no hub, eu uso o seguinte código.

```
await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("AtualizaCardOP","mensagem 1");
```

Mas o que estou tentando fazer agora é enviar outra mensagem para todos os usuário exeto pra quem fez a requisição. Tentei de muitas maneiras mas não consegui uma maneira de fazer.

Não pude deixar de notar que existe os metodos `AllExcept` e `GroupExcept` dentro de `_hubContext.Clients.`. mas o impressionante é que não consigo fazer eles funcionar.

Exemplos tentados e que não funcionam:

```
string idUserSignalR = this.User.Identity.Name;
await _hubContext.Clients.AllExcept(idUserSignalR).SendAsync("AtualizaPosicaoCardOP", "Mensagem aqui");

await _hubContext.Clients.GroupExcept(idUserSignalR, idUserSignalR).SendAsync("AtualizaPosicaoCardOP", "Mensagem aqui");
```

Aqui uma imagem que não entendi como fazer funcionar devido o segundo parametro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que estou fazendo errado?

tem como fazer o que eu desejo?

Comment: pela documentação, precisa passar o nome do grupo e uma lista de clientIds para usar esse método: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.ihubclients-1.groupexcept?view=aspnetcore-7.04  o objeto de `Context` tem o usuário, grupo, identities, etc, deve ter o que precisa pra filtrar

Comment: No meu caso, como eu coleto essa lista de ids???